# Facebook share dialog is giving empty message

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

my facebook app is not in sandbox, its live.

While sharing a dialog , I am getting empty message like this :

[image]

My **href** is as follows :

```
<a title="send to Facebook" 
    href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?  
    app_id=1440979716022445&  
    link=http://ariddleaday.com&
    picture=http://ariddleaday.com/cat.png&  
    name=Can%20you%20help%20Jimmy&  
    caption=A%20Riddle%20A%20Day& 
    description=Try%20this%20and%20have%20fun&
    message=Jimmy goes to school . His friends Shirushi , Harjot  and Aafreen asks him what always ends everything? Jimmy calls you for help , whats the answer ?&
    redirect_uri=http://ariddleaday.com"
    >
<span>
    Send this Riddle to Facebook 
</span>
</a>
```

I have added this function which is called on click , but still I am getting sameoutput

```
 function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri: 'http://ariddleaday.com',
          link: 'https://ariddleaday.com',
          picture: 'http://ariddleaday.com/cat.png',
          name: 'Riddle of the Day',
          caption: 'Can you help Jimmy ?',
          description: 'Jimmy goes to school . His friends Shirushi , Harjot  and Aafreen asks him what always ends everything? Jimmy calls you for help , whats the answer ?'
        };

         function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Thank you for sharing !";
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);

        return false;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out in the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fariddleaday.com

The image is missing something:

```
<meta property="og:image" content=".cat.png" />
```

All those parameters for the feed dialog are deprecated, you have to use Open Graph tags in the shared URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9

Comment: I am studying graph api , How can I set meta tag for image ? Because whatever I try , I am getting error .

Comment: put them in your html head section...

Comment: added an additional link for sharing in my answer. if you get an error, please say with one ;)

Comment: image is working fine now , trying to set feed dialog

Comment: I have updated the question , please check bottom part

Comment: so what is not working exactly? and why are you still using those deprecated parameters?

Comment: side note: you cannot get a reliable callback without authorizing the user with the publish_actions permission. check out the docs.